# Is there a way to get Expression Web style CSS code hints in the PhpStorm IDE?

Tags: phpstorm

Microsoft Expression Web has a very nice code hint feature for CSS so that when you type in a property it lists all the options at the top along with a drop down for code completion.

[image: Example]

Is there a way to replicate this behavior in PhpStorm?

Comment: In theory (how it works for other languages, e.g. PHP) it supposed to be "View | Parameter Info" .. but apparently it does not work like that for CSS. You can create new ticket for this at Issue Tracker: http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/dashboard/WI

Comment: It actually works but is not as good as Expressions Web where it is set up to show automatically by default, highlights the current parameter that you are inputting on the list and has the appropriate auto complete drop down show up by automatically. Is there any way to set it up so it shows the parameter information and code suggestion drop down automatically? - or is that just a bug because the code completion setting changes don't seem to work?

Comment: Settings | Editor | Code Completion

Comment: It does not seem to work on css in 3.0.3, need to ctrl+p, ctrl+space

Comment: Cannot suggest anything more -- maybe there is a reason for that .. or maybe it's just a bug. You know what you can do about it -- ask devs directly (see my 2nd comment)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments as of PhpStorm 4.0.1, this feature is available in the IDE but does not work on CSS code.

Answer (score 0):

You can almost get there. Start typing a property. PhpStorm displays autocomplete suggestions:

[image]

Hit your escape key to clear the autocomplete suggestions box, and then press Cmd + P on a mac and PhpStorm will display the CSS property's signature:

[image]

It's not quite automatic, but it's pretty close.